# Auto generated PDF won't add itself to the printqueue

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

Pre info:
Acrobat reader: 10.1.3 (updated 2 days ago)
Vista 32bit.

At my company we are using a website controlled by a postalervice to print forms that we fill out which are then created into a PDF
A week ago, we had a local printer set as standard.
What you do is you go onto this website, type in a lot of information and hit 'print' then it generates a PDF from your input, which it opens shortly
Then adds it to the 'standard set printer'

At least thats what it used to do. A few days ago I added a network printer as standard, as we are trying to remove all those local printers.
It works fine, when I try to print something online or a word document it comes right out in the new printer..

All except when I try to use this site to print PDF. It still opens the autogenerated PDF and says "Printing too 'correctName'"

But nothing is ever added into the printqueue..
I called the support on the website, they said all that needed to be done was make sure that their site was a 'trusted' site.
I did that, added the site as trusted and made sure I'm using a windows account with Admin rights. It now even says when I browse it
that this is a trusted website and all protection is turned off.

Now Funny info:. When the autogenerated PDF opens, if I'm fast and hit the 'print' sign in Acrobat reader, it will actually print.
But I only have a window of 1-2 seconds before it closes and supposedly makes sure to print itself

So can anyone help me, .. Cause I have no idea what the problem is.. I don't understand why it worked on a local printer and not a network printer.. and I don't understand that I can hit 'print' on the autogenerated PDF document and then it works.